# Migrating to MySQL 8 calculating the RANK Error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-8.0

Trying to calculate the RANK of a ticket from the Table, on MySQL 8 getting "**You have an error in your SQL syntax**", but is working fine on lower MySQL versions. Cannot figure it out, Thank you for the help:

```
SELECT z.rank FROM (
SELECT t.rb , t.tid, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
FROM br t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
ORDER BY rb ASC
) as z WHERE tid= '100100'
```

Comment: MySQL 8 has the built-in `RANK()` window function. Use that. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html

Comment: They've changed how you're allowed to use user variables in 8.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the error you get is this

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank ....
```

Well, that's cause `rank` is a reserved keyword since MySQL v8.0.2. [Refer doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

What you can do with your current query is simply change `rank` to something else like `t_rank` and you should get the query working again.

```
SELECT z.t_rank FROM (
SELECT t.rb , t.tid, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS t_rank
FROM br t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
ORDER BY rb ASC
) as z WHERE tid= '100100'
```

However, on MySQL v8+, you can directly use `RANK()` function without needing to use variables anymore like this:

```
SELECT t.rb , t.tid, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rb) AS t_rank
FROM br t
ORDER BY rb;
```

That should return you the same (and possibly more accurate) results.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8K5x6im8)

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention, you can still use `rank` keyword by wrapping it in backticks (`) but I personally wouldn't because I work with some programming code that uses backticks a lot so it wouldn't be ideal for me to use it.